# Vim substitute with ascending numbers inside a pattern

Tags: vim, replace, substitution

I have a pattern like this:

```
word0word
word0word
word0word
```

And I need to number the ocurrences of the pattern like this:

```
word1word
word2word
word3word
```

I found that I can do this:

```
:let @a=1 | %s/word0/\='word'.(@a+setreg('a',@a+1))/g
```

But it omits the rest of the pattern (the second "word", which I need to include to identify the pattern).
Is there a way to include the rest of the pattern? I tried:

```
:let @a=1 | %s/word0word/\='word'.(@a+setreg('a',@a+1))'word'/g
```

But that returns an error.
I also thought about combining this with `\zs` and `\ze`, but I'm not sure how to approach that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second pattern you're just missing a `.` (to indicate concatenation).
This will work :

```
:let @a=1 | %s/word0word/\='word'.(@a+setreg('a',@a+1)).'word'/g
                                          " this one --^
```

Note that if you want to use capture groups in a subreplace expression you'll need to use `submatch(x)` instead of `\x` (replace `x` with the number of the match, starting at `1`) :

```
:let @a=1 | %s/\vword0(\w+)/\='word'.(@a+setreg('a',@a+1)).submatch(1)/g
```

See `:h sub-replace-\=` for more informations on using subreplace expressions.

Comment: That missing dot did it! And thanks for the tip, I will need to investigate submatches further.